# Eliminar primera aparición de dígito en una lista

Tags: python, lista, funciones

Una función que recibe una lista de números y un número. Se recorre la lista y se elimina la primera aparición del número en la lista.

Ejemplo:

Recibido: `[1,2,3,4,5,8] y 8.`

Devuelto: `[1,2,3,4,5]`

Answer (score 0):

Para eliminar la primera aparición de un objeto en una lista se puede hacer uso del método `remove()`

```
def eliminar_primera_aparicion(lista, numero):
        lista.remove(numero)
        return lista

print(eliminar_primera_aparicion([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4], 4)) #[1, 2, 3, 5, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar la función `remove()` solo que debes tener en cuenta si le vas a pasar una lista por parámetro o una variable que contenga una lista ya que `remove(value)` quita el primer valor que esté dentro de sus parámetros me explico

si necesitas algo asi:

```
def borrarElemento(lista,elemBorrar):
    lista.remove(elemBorrar)

myList = [1,2,3,4]
elemento = 3
borrarElemento(myList,elemento)
print(myList)
```

no te haría falta un `return lista` en la función pero si le pasas la lista por parámetro:

```
def borrarElemento(lista,elemBorrar):
    lista.remove(elemBorrar)
    # aqui si es necesario un return
    return lista

listaBorrada = borrarElemento([1,2,3],2)
print(myLislistaBorrada)
```